# Map/iterator incremental error

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code throwing debug assertion map/iterator incremental error ..

```
void ClassA::Remove()
{
    std::map<int, CVClassB*>::iterator it(m_p.begin());
    while ( it != m_p.end() )
    {
        if (it->first >= 0)
        {
            m_p.erase(it);
            it++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Can you please let me know what is the error

Comment: This is `C++` not `C`. They are different.

Comment: Any question that asks about error, **must include the complete error message**. Edit your question and add necessary information.

Comment: Please ask your debugger what is the error, and then you can ask here how to fix it

Comment: This is not `[mfc]` either.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) invalidates the iterator on which it operates. So it is not safe to increment it afterwards. But `erase()` does return the next iterator for you:

```
it = m_p.erase(it);
```

Also, you only increment `it` *inside* the `if`, so unless *all* the keys are `>=0`, you will get stuck in an infinite loop. You probably wanted something like:

```
// delete all keys >= 0
if (it->first>=0) {
    it = m_p.erase(it); // erase and increment
}
else {
    ++it; // just increment
}
```

Also, as Vlad's answer alludes to, who manages the lifetime of the `CVClassB*`? Do you need to `delete` it? Why use a pointer at all, you can probably store the value in the map directly. (Or use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).

Comment: i tried but its not working crashing second time at the starting of while loop

Comment: @NarasimhaRaoK You need to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the crash then, because based on the minimal code shown in the question, I can't offer any more insight.

Comment: its working as per ur suggestion i will check the output ...once

Answer (score 1):

Write the loop like

```
while ( it != m_p.end() )
{
    if (it->first >= 0)
    {
        it = m_p.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Also it seems you should delete the object pointed to by the erased iterator.
For example

```
        delete *it;
        it = m_p.erase(it);
```

Comment: Long liveth the `std::map<int, gsl::owner<CVClassB>>`!

Comment: No don't do that either. Your iterator will still be invalid. Delete the objects pointed to WITHOUT removing them from the map first.

Comment: @systemcpro I have not understood what you mean.

Comment: If you create an iterator for example `iter = collection.begin()` and then erase an element of the collection inside the loop `while(iter - end) collection.erase(something)` then the iterator will most likely become invalid. In this case it is best to not call 'erase' inside the loop. Just delete the object 'delete iter->second' inside the loop and then at the end when the loop has completed call `collection.clear()`

Comment: @systemcpro Again I have understood nothing. I showed a valid loop in my answer.

Comment: OK. Assume the collection has one item. The `begin()` returns that. Now in the loop you call `erase` which removes the one and only element. So now what is the iterator "pointing to" (for want of a better word). You can't compare it to `end` it doesn't exist anymore you just erased it

Comment: @systemcpro If you look through the loop one more you will see that the iterator is set to the returned value of the method erase. So it will be equal to the end() iterator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104385/discussion-between-systemcpro-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: presumably you mean `delete it->second`, rather than `delete *it` . Although it's not clear from OP's post whether these are "owning" pointers or not.

Comment: Yes true, I wrote "if you want to delete them" :)

Comment: @systemcpro `m_p.end()` is always valid ; if there is only one element then `it = m_p.erase(it);` will leave `it == m_p.end()`

Answer (score -3):

Your invalidating the iterator by removing inside the loop but in any case all that does is clear the map. Just call `m_p.clear()` and it will do exactly what you are trying to do. Although not sure what your trying to do is what you intended to do but that's another issue.

If you want to delete the objects pointed to then delete them then clear the map.

```
for(item : m_p)
   delete item->second;
m_p.clear();

//done
```

Comment: Please let me know  the answer

Comment: `m_p.clear()` would remove all entries, whereas OP's code only removes entries with non-negative key.  Also there was no mention of whether `delete` is required.

Comment: True but i wrote "IF you want to delete the objects" but point taken

Comment: @MM i tried but its not working crashing second time at the starting of while loop